# What "guys" is Anthony referring to?

Tags: jumanji-the-next-level

Anthony being sucked into video game jumanji:

> Anthony: What...? We haven't even picked **our guys** yet!

What "guys" is Anthony referring to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 'guys' they are referring to are the game's [Player Characters](https://jumanji.fandom.com/wiki/Jumanji:_Welcome_to_the_Jungle#Meet_the_Avatars).

In the first movie, before they got sucked in, they were able to choose who they would become in the world of Jumanji. This time the game made that choice for them.